# Does VMware Player require Windows license?

Tags: vmware

If I am correct that VMware Player in Ubuntu doesn't require to install the full Windows OS. Does it mean that it doesn't need the Windows license to install and run Windows applications, just like Wine? Thanks.

Comment: Ask Microsoft and/or VMWare =)

Comment: wine itself is not made by microsoft, and some components (windows .dll not included withe wine) and applications do require a licence (most people install apps they already purchased such as games or MS Office).

Comment: Does windows.dll requires Windows license?

Comment: See https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main "There are of course DLLs that Wine does not currently implement very well (or at all).In case Wine complains about a missing DLL, you should check whether this file is a publicly available DLL or a custom DLL belonging to your program. In the latter case, check that you have installed your program correctly.

Comment: cotinued - 

Most often applications will assume that a required redistributable package has already been installed and subsequently fail to run when the required dependencies are not met. For example:

err:module:import_dll Library MFC42.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\Program Files\\Foo\\Bar.dll") not found
Redistributable packages which install the necessary runtimes can be obtained through the use of winetricks. Note these components are subject to their own license and are not part of the Wine project. You should refer to the application's AppDB entry for advice on what is required

Answer (score 1):

You will need the appropriate licence for the operating system you plan on running virtualised.

This is different to wine which implements various Windows APIs on Linux - it does not run any Microsoft software, which is why no Windows licence is required.

Comment: Does VMware player use a part of Windows OS for running a Windows program? as opposed to Wine which reimplements some part of Windows OS?

Comment: absolutely. With vmware you are running windows for which you need a licence from Microsoft. With wine you are runing open source code that does not require a licences from Microsoft. Then the software you run may or may not require additional licenses with either option. Note: open source has it's own licensing ...